# Maintaining state of listbox in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have dual list box in **MVC**. Id's of the all items in selected listbox needs to be posted the server. Model has three properties defined

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailItems {get;set;}
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedItems {get;set;}
string SelectedItemIds {get;set;}
```

I have populated `availItems` and `selectedItems` listboxes with different names and `SelectedItemIds` property as hiddenfield. Javascript updates the hiddenfield if the user add/removes items from the listbox. In httpost, I receive only `selectedItemIds` since name of listboxes are changed, which is expected behavior.

Problem is when the model is invalid or any exception occurs, return `View(model)` gets executed, the listbox populates empty values but `hiddenfield` contains values of modified items. And when again user submits the page, the values from `hiddenfield` get posted but displayed items will be from db. I followed this approach of using `hiddenfield` instead of selecting all items before submit (using javascript) because it doesn't harm if non-js user submits the page. The values from `hiddenfield` gets pickedup.

Any ideas of how to deal with above situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not repopulate that information into the model before doing `View(model)`? I'm assuming you have code similar to:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) 
{
    //...all is ok
}
else 
{
    model.AvailItems = // repopulate
    model.SelectedItems = // repopulate
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes, so modelstate is gone i.e, user newly added/removed items are gone.

Comment: You mean the selected ids you have in your hidden field are not taken into account? You can always parse the value in it and select the items on $(document).ready(), or parse it server-side and adjust SelectedItems prior to rendering the view, no?

Comment: @Romeo, I have dual list i.e., one listbox contains available items and when the user selects any item, they get pushed to other listbox2. On submit, all items from listbox2 (not just selected items) needs to be saved. Hidden field holds id's of listbox2 items and is manipulated on client when items are added/removed. Now, if model is invalid, listbox2 items are populated from db and hidden field from modelstate i.e., if user added new items 5 to existing items 2,3.The hidden field contains 2,3,5 but displayed would be 2,3. If he re-submits the page, items 2,3,5 get posted.Hope I am clear now.

Comment: I think I am able to solve the problem. If modelstate is invalid, I am populating listbox2 items based on the hidden field.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by "parse it server-side". To keep the lists in sync with what comes in the hidden field.